# split a list into groups of n and assign group ID with Python

Tags: python, grouping

Given  a list of tuple, with each tuple is a value for a pair of variable.

```
[(0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.4), (0.0, 0.8), (0.0, 1.2000000000000002), (0.0, 1.6), (0.4, 0.0), (0.4, 0.4)]
```

The objective is to split this list of tuple into N group and append the group ID in each of the tuple.

Currently, the following code answer the objective

```
from itertools import product

import numpy as np


def split(a, n):
    k, m = divmod(len(a), n)
    return (a[i*k+min(i, m):(i+1)*k+min(i+1, m)] for i in range(n))

pair_var=list(product(np.arange(*(0.0,2,0.4)), np.arange(*(0.0,2,0.4))))
ngroup=2
pair_var_gr=list(split(pair_var, ngroup))

new_group=[]
for ndex,ltup in enumerate(pair_var_gr):
  for dtup in ltup:
    m=list(dtup)
    m.append(ndex)
    new_group.append(m)
```

Expected output

```
[[0.0, 0.0, 0], [0.0, 0.4, 0], [0.0, 0.8, 0], [0.0, 1.2000000000000002, 0], [0.0, 1.6, 0], [0.4, 0.0, 0], [0.4, 0.4, 0]]
```

However, I wonder whether there is compact or proper ways of achieving the above?

Comment: why in the expected output the group id (the new added element at index 2) is always 0?

Comment: It looks like this could be a simple list comprehension, unless I'm misunderstanding. A simple example without the group id could be, give `input = [(0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.4), (0.0, 0.8), (0.0, 1.2000000000000002), (0.0, 1.6), (0.4, 0.0), (0.4, 0.4)]`, something like `output = [[item[0], item[1]] for item in input]`, with your group ID derived in the comprehension and appended there, correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [more-itertools](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.divide) to divide a list into N groups.

```py
new_group = [[tuple(pair) + (group_id,) for pair in group_of_pairs]
             for group_id, group_of_pairs in enumerate(more_itertools.divide(ngroup, pair_var))]
```

Or you could also use [numpy.array_split](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html) or [numpy.split](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.split.html).
This is much faster when dealing with large data, but note that this method requires all values to be the same dtype.

Answer (score 0):

Without the group ID, this could simply be accomplished with a list comprehension, like so:

````
new_list = [[item[0], item[1]] for item in output]

print(new_list)```

output: `[[0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.4], [0.0, 0.8], [0.0, 1.2000000000000002], [0.0, 1.6], [0.4, 0.0], [0.4, 0.4]]`

Adding an int of the first element just to fill in the Group ID space for example:

`new_list = [[item[0], item[1], int(item[0])] for item in output]`

output: `[[0.0, 0.0, 0], [0.0, 0.4, 0], [0.0, 0.8, 0], [0.0, 1.2000000000000002, 0], [0.0, 1.6, 0], [0.4, 0.0, 0], [0.4, 0.4, 0]]`

That Group ID assignment could be tweaked to fit your needs in the comprehension without need for numpy, I'm guessing.
````